# Is a database name needed with an Amazon RDS url?

Tags: r, database, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, r-dbi

Sorry I can't give an MRE. This is from a programming task where I'm supposed to process data from a database. However, I'm having trouble accessing the database altogether, and I am allowed to use code fora in a limited way.

I was given a URL of the form:

`foo.bar.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com`

as well as a username, password, and port #.

I am trying to access the database from R using `dbConnect`

```r
>  connection = dbConnect(
+   RPostgres::Postgres(), 
+   host="foo.bar.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com", 
+   user="some_user",
+   password='pa$$w0rd',
+   port=5###
+ )
Error: FATAL:  database "user2" does not exist
```

```r
>  connection = dbConnect(
+   RPostgres::Postgres(), 
+   host="foo.bar.us-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com", 
+   dbname="guess",
+   user="some_user",
+   password='pa$$w0rd',
+   port=5###
+ )
Error: FATAL:  database "guess" does not exist
```

Given the information I have, can the URL help me from within AWS?

### Edit

They just gave the database name, and using that the connection works.

However, I'll leave this up in case any useful answers or discussions emerge.

Comment: You are successfully contacting the database, so it is not a networking issue. It sounds like the information they gave you is incorrect?

Comment: I should have said in the edit that now that I have the dbname, I the connection works.

Comment: Rather than edit the solution into your question, post what worked as an answer and (after the 24-hour wait period) accept it. Then your question will show up as resolved.